# Sign-In with Google in MVC and use JWT based ASP.NET Core Web API C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, google-oauth

I'm completely new to C# Net 6 and Web Development in general.

I would like to integrate something like [this](https://dev.to/christianzink/how-to-sign-in-with-google-in-angular-and-use-jwt-based-net-core-api-authentication-rsa-1anl), but using Core Web App MVC, instead of Angular.

So far I have followed, Ms guide, to deploy Google Authentication, and I'm able to log in  with google

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(
options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ClientID").Value;
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:ClientSecret").Value;
    
});
```

**but I'm not able to get the idToken, it always returns null**

```
var idToken= await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
```

the code to validate the token from google on the API, and return my JWT, would be:

```
GoogleJsonWebSignature.Payload payload  = GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(data.IdToken, settings).Result;
return Ok(new { AuthToken = _jwtGenerator.CreateUserAuthToken(payload.Email) });
```

As I have stated, I´m completely new to Web Development, if this is not the right solution or is there a better more logical approach, I will be open to try it.

Thanks in advance for your help.